# Perform search with filled textboxes only

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have a search bar with different search options, I want the SQL query to only search with the filled textboxes

I made a simple SP that worked fine when I had a search bar with only two search options (Name and Code) using if statements (not the best practice). However now that I had search bbars with 4-5 elements the IF statements don't seem like the best practice for performance

This is the procedure I made for the case where I only had 2 search options:

```
@Code_client nvarchar(50),
@Intitule_client varchar(100)
as 
IF (@Code_client is not NULL AND @Code_client!='')
   BEGIN
   IF (@Intitule_client IS not NULL AND @Intitule_client!='')
      select * from Clients where Code_client=@Code_client and Intitule_client=@Intitule_client
   ELSE
      select * from Clients where Code_client=@Code_client
   END
ELSE IF (@Intitule_client is not null AND @Intitule_client!='')
    BEGIN
    select * from Clients where Intitule_client=@Intitule_client
    END
```

But for this case, I have 4 search options like this:

```
<div id="chercher_employe" class="Rechercher">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="chercher_employe_Nom" CssClass="Input" placeholder="Nom employe"></asp:TextBox>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="chercher_employe_Departement" CssClass="Input" placeholder="Departement"></asp:TextBox>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="chercher_employe_occupation" CssClass="Input" placeholder="Occupation"></asp:TextBox>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="chercher_employe_IntituleProfil" CssClass="Input" placeholder="Profil"></asp:TextBox>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CssClass="button">  <i class="fas fa-search"></i> </asp:LinkButton>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

I can't figure out another way except for using the if statements with C# or SQL, any suggestions please?

Comment: you could have a collection of textBoxes then select all where !string.isnullorempty, then for each one exectute the appropriate query or conjoin them if you are sending a sproc

Comment: `select * from Clients where (Code_client=@Code_client or @Code_client is null) and (Intitule_client=@Intitule_client or @Intitule_client is null) and...`

Comment: There are multiple ways to do this with static SQL, for starters [this](http://sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html#BasicStaticSQL). The rest of that article is worth a read too, though, because there are some performance pitfalls to consider with dynamic queries like these.

Comment: I suggest have a look at [kitchen sink queries](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example/) and [Catch-all queries](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/). Dynamic SQL is likely to be the way to go, but if this logic is controlled from the application side then you just need to build your SQL statement appropriately and not include the clauses where the parameter has no value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Larnu and @jarlh proposition is what worked best for me.
This link explains it very well:
 https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example/

Thank you everyone for your answers, appreciate it :)

(Kindly write your answer down here so I can accept it if anyone had the same problem ^^)

Answer (score 0):

An if statement is nothing more than a logical implication

`a -> b` if a then b

which can also be written as

`!a or b` not a or b

So your if statement

```
IF (@Intitule_client IS not NULL AND @Intitule_client!='')
      select * from Clients where Code_client=@Code_client and Intitule_client=@Intitule_client
```

can be translated to (using De Morgan's Laws to simplify double negation (`not(a or b) <=> not(a) and not(b)`)

```
SELECT * 
FROM Clients
WHERE (@Intitule_client IS NULL OR @Intitule_client = '' OR Intitule_client = @Intitule_client) AND Code_client = @Code_client
```

You can then use this pattern to construct more complex queries.

Comment: Careful mind, as this will likely end up with some bad cached query plans.